# event listener in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am having a task which will listen for certain events and kick-off other functions.

This function (the listener) subscribes to a kafka topic and runs forever, or at least until it will get a 'stop' event.

Wrapping this as an airflow operator doesn't seem to work properly.
Meaning, if I send the stop event, it will not process it, or anything else for that matter.
Is it possible to run busy loop functions in airflow ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case?  A task that runs forever would disrupt the rest of the DAG's tasks from running.  Airflow has sensors which can be used to poll repeatedly with a timeout at the task level, but there isn't really a mechanism to push into Airflow externally like from a Kafka consumer.  One idea you might consider is running the Kafka listener independent of Airflow and then having that trigger DAG runs.

Comment: Well, I'll have a task in airflow which subscribes to a kafka topic and it will run until it will see a certain event in the kafka topic( 'signal' : 'stop' ) and then that task in airflow should terminate.

This is the last task in airflow.
I am thinking of having it separately as a micro service. I don't need to kick off the dag.

Comment: task chain:
1. dump csv file into kafka
2. signal to a topic that I've started dumping data into a kafka topic. (topic for signals is called meta)

this is the listener task
3. listen to that meta topic for other signals ( from another microservice )
 3.1. as soon as I see a certain event, I kick-off an aggregation on some tables and dump the result into another db
 3.2. listen for the stop signal, if encounter, stop the listener task in airflow.

Comment: I think an airflow sensor should also do it.

Answer (score 4):

No, do not run infinite loops in an Airflow task.

Airflow is designed as a batch processor - long/infinite running tasks are counter to it's entire scheduling and processing model and while it might "work", it will lock up a task runner slot.